# Can't use final in Flutter(Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax, final

I can't understand what's the problem in my code.
This is my code:

[image]

And this is the error:

[image]

Comment: You're expected to place `widgets` in the `ListView `children property not declare a variable.

Comment: You can move `final rows = await db.queryAllRows();` directly after '`if (rowCount != 0){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare variables inside a list.

Move this line `final rows = await db.queryAllRows();` and put it after this line: `if (rowCount != 0) {`.